# LINQ to return Boolean

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have to check whether the collection has two primary key values. I have done like,

//Code

```
Dim query = TableColumnsCollection.GroupBy(Function(x) x.IsPrimaryKey).Where(Function(y) y.Count() > 1)
```

Now i have to return the type as `boolean` when the count exceeds more than "One".

When the count exceeds 1 then it should be "True" else "False".

I should be getting something like,

```
Dim blnFlag As Boolean= False

blnFlag=//Query here ???
```

When i tried to assign the above query i'm getting the below error.

```
"Value of type IEnumarable cannot be converted to Boolean"
```

How can i do that?

Comment: I can't compile your query in my head. I agree with the C# compiler. Please explain what you want. It looks like you want to check if more than one column `IsPrimaryKey`. But it could as easily be that you want to find if there are more than one columns with `IsPrimaryKey == false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Any` instead of `Where`:

```
Dim containsDups As Boolean = TableColumnsCollection.
        GroupBy(Function(x) x.IsPrimaryKey).
        Any(Function(y) y.Count() > 1)
```

but you could also keep the `Where` if you need it for other things and use `Any` afterwards:

```
Dim allDups = TableColumnsCollection.
    GroupBy(Function(x) x.IsPrimaryKey).
    Where(Function(y) y.Count() > 1)
Dim containsDups As Boolean = allDups.Any()
```

Comment: I doubt that is what he is after. It would return false for all TableCollection with more than 3 items. Which would make a rather boring collection.

Comment: @Aron Did you mean *It wouldn't* ?

Comment: @Aron: it returns `true` only if it at least  one primary-key  is a duplicate. I don't understand what you mean with "3 items". OP hasn't even mentioned what `TableCollection` actually is. I've presumed a collection of objects with a property `IsPrimaryKey`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel nice spot...getting to the end of the day here >_<

Comment: @TimSchmelter How? You are not checking the `group.Key` anywhere so it will check all the groups(true and false). Am I missing something?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Maybe I am a little presumptuous, but any property called `IsXXX` tends to be `bool`. Assuming that there is no `bool.FileNotFound`, and applying pigeon hole theory, when the initial collection.Count > 3, then 3 > 2. Thus there will always be more than one pigeon in each hole. ERGO for all collections with more than 3 items, it will have a constant return value.

Comment: @Aron: At last the penny's dropped! I've understood `IsPrimaryKey` as `PrimaryKey`-column, so not as a boolean column.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: what is `IsPrimaryKey`, a `Boolean` property? You need to use the actual property that is the primary-key.

Comment: I'm aware of that Tim My point is same as @Aron, This will always return true if columns count is >=3. Am I right?

Comment: While not c# for me it gave me the right direction to go for a great answer got my six lines down to one